# increase targetSdkVersion for androidTest

Tags: android, testing, gradle

Currently I'm facecing a problem I am not able to solve. Due to a bug I have to set a lower targetsdkVersion to 25 (with is the maximun possible target version at the time of this post)

Its solution can take me much time to solve, so meanwhile I want to set a lower targetSdkVersion for production builts and 25 just for tesing (androidTest variation).

I know I can do it by adding a new flavor, but I'd like to avoid this.

My question is, how can I set a different targetSdkVersion just for androidTest than for the rest of variants/configurations?

Comment: change in `manifest` file.

Comment: Why would you avoid using flavors? I believe that's the recommended way of dealing with multiple configurations for the same code base. Otherwise you would need to manually switch the gradle files before each run. Flavors are precisely used for this case I believe.

Comment: An androidTest built already generates a separate apk with its own minSdkVersion and targetsdkVersion. I don't see the needed of using a new flavor just to this.

Comment: It should be possible to set a different target on androidTest apk. Anyway, recently I was able to reduce all my flavors from 16 to just 4. I am a bit bored about flavors and I wont use a new one if is likely there is no need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to achieve it. I finally had to generate a new flavor as follows:

```
android {
    def defaultTargetSdk = 24
    def androidTestTargetSdk = 25

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion defaultTargetSdk
    }

    productFlavors {
        target24 {
        }
        target25 {
            targetSdkVersion androidTestTargetSdk
        }
    }

    // Remove target25Release as it's used only for testing purpose and wont be not needed on production.
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name
        def flavorName = variant.getFlavors().get(0).name

        if (buildTypeName.equals('release') && flavorName.startsWith('target25')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true);
        }
    }
}
```

As I already need a variation with debug buildType and target 24 I only remove my target25Release variation, but if hadn't needed it I could have writen the following to set target 25 to all debug variations:

```
android {
    def defaultTargetSdk = 24
    def androidTestTargetSdk = 25

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion defaultTargetSdk
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {    
            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion androidTestTargetSdk
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code for `minimum sdk level` and `taargeted sdk level` in your `manifest` file as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />  //replace 3 with required minimum version
 <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />   //replace 8 with required target version

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am afraid this didn't worked for me. I am already setting my targetSdkVersion by gradle as my default target and if I write it on a manifest file at androidTest directory it is override by gradle setting again my default target